# Unable to POST a request to a server using CURL in BASH

Tags: string, bash, curl, post, get

I have been trying to run a BASH script which posts a request to an SMS server and on successful execution a message is received on the mentioned mobile number. Script is as shown below:

```
curl -k -X POST "http://192.168.10.3/u=admin&h=452ba065ebd1723598a51c7eca11d362&op=pv&to=1234567891&msg=Hello+to+all"
```

The above script is working fine. The message "Hello to all" is being received on the mobile number 1234567891. This number is however hard coded in the URL. In the actual scenario the mobile number would be available in a variable and the SMS would be sent to the mobile number available in this variable.

I have tried scripts like:

```
mobile_number="1234567891"
curl -k -X POST "http://192.168.10.3/u=admin&h=452ba065ebd1723598a51c7eca11d362&op=pv&to=$mobile_number&msg=Message+From+world"
```

and

```
x="http://192.168.10.3/u=admin&h=452ba065ebd1723598a51c7eca11d362&op=pv&to="
x+="1234567891
x+=&msg=Hello+to+all"
curl -k -X POST $x
```

However, i have been unsuccessful in executing them successfully. It would be of great help if someone could help me with the syntax.

Comment: Try out this principle, bash is different language than c++ or so :-): (I put it to answers to clarify the code which is not ok in comment) ...

Answer (score 0):

Try out this principle, bash is different language than c++ or so :-):

```
#!/bin/bash
to="1234567891"
msg="Hello+to+all"
u="admin"
hash="452ba065ebd1723598a51c7eca11d362"
op="pv"
ip="192.168.10.3"
url="http://${ip}/u=admin&h=${hash}&op=${op}&to=${to}&msg=${msg}"

echo ${url}
```

Than : `curl -k -X POST $url should work fine.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am getting the following error on employing the above method


ERROR:
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in url

Comment: Add -v to curl params. It will be more verbose to solve problems. I tested it on my debian and it seems it works fine.